# Concanate rows on Sybase by Id

Tags: sap-ase

I´m having results on a table like:

[image]

What I wanted to do is have result like:

[image]

How can I do this because Sybase don t have concatenate method?

Comment: ASE does not provide a list()/group_concat() functionality so you'll have to write your own; if you know you'll only concatenate 2 values then you could write a 2-way join; if you need to concatenate an unknown number of values then you'll need to write a cursor/looping method

Comment: Do you have an example how can I use in this case cursor/looping method?

Comment: There is actually a way in ASE to concatenate across a result set inside a query, but that uses an obscure aspect of the UPDATE statement (not updating any data, but using a variable). It's probably better (as in:" more understandable and maintainable) to rewrite the query in order to use a loop or N-way join.

Comment: RobV could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

setup:

```
create table mytab
(id varchar(10)
,b  varchar(30))
go

insert mytab values ('233.263','DDDD')
insert mytab values ('233.263','AAAAAQ')
insert mytab values ('233.283','22223')
insert mytab values ('233.283','333333')
go

-- #lists will hold intermediate results
create table #lists
(id     varchar(10)
,b_list varchar(1000))
go
```

declare our cursor:

NOTE: OP did not state how the `b` column values are to be sorted so we'll stick with alphabetical sorting for this example.

```
declare mycur cursor
for
select id,b
from   mytab
order by id,b
for read only
go
```

loop through cursor, appending `b` values to `@b_list` for each distinct `id`:

```
declare @id     varchar(10),
        @id_old varchar(10),
        @b      varchar(30),
        @b_list varchar(1000)

select  @id_old = NULL

open mycur

fetch mycur into @id, @b

while @@sqlstatus = 0
begin
    -- if new @id value, save old @id/@b_list pair
    if @id != isnull(@id_old,'UNDEFINED')
    begin
        if @b_list is not NULL
        begin
            insert #lists values (@id_old, @b_list)
        end

        select  @id_old = @id,
                @b_list = NULL
    end

    select  @b_list = @b_list + case when @b_list is not NULL then '|' end + @b

    fetch mycur into @id, @b
end

-- save last @id/@b_list pair
if @b_list is not NULL
begin
    insert #lists values (@id, @b_list)
end

close mycur

deallocate cursor mycur
go
```

display results:

```
select * from #lists
go

 id      b_list
 ------- ------------
 233.263 AAAAAQ|DDDD
 233.283 22223|333333
```